# Passing a pointer to a function but the pointer remains unchanged

Tags: c, pointers, gtk, gtk3

I have created the following two files to illustrate what my problem is.

*main.c*

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include "app_struct.h"

static void activation(GtkApplication *app, gpointer user_data);
static void check_file(GFile *file);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int status;

        GtkApplication *test = gtk_application_new("idk.for.now.test", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
        g_signal_connect(test, "activate", G_CALLBACK(activation), NULL);
        status = g_application_run(G_APPLICATION(test), argc, argv);
        g_object_unref(test);
        return status;
}

static void activation(GtkApplication *app, gpointer user_data)
{
        // create app my_struct
        struct app_struct my_struct;

        g_print("%d\n", my_struct.file);
        // set no file
        my_struct.file = NULL;
        g_print("%d\n", my_struct.file);
        check_file(my_struct.file);
        g_print("%d\n", my_struct.file);

        // add application to my_struct
        my_struct.app = app;
}

static void check_file(GFile *file)
{
        g_print("%d\n", file);
        file = (GFile *) 0xdeadbeef;
        g_print("%d\n", file);
}
```

*app_struct.h*

```
#ifndef APP_STRUCT_H
#define APP_STRUCT_H
struct app_struct
{
        GtkApplication *app; 
        GFile *file;
};
#endif
```

I want to modify the original file pointer in the `check_file` function, but I find that I cannot do that for some reason.

Here is what I get when I run this program:

```
-1137322208
0
0
-559038737
0
```

It seems that `check_file` function gets only the copy of `my_struct.file`, but since it accepts a pointer, shouldn't the value of `my_struct.file`, which is an address, be assigned to `GFile *file`, which is supposed to be set to an address, as if I wrote `GFile *file = my_struct.file;`? Then `file` and `mystruct.file` would point to the same location in memory.

Comment: Pointers are passed by value too. You'll need to pass a pointer to the pointer, or return the new pointer.

Comment: `my_struct.file` in `activation` and `file` in `check_file` are different pointer objects that are pointing to the same thing. Changing the value of one of the pointer objects does not magically change the value of the other one.

Comment: There is a duplicate, I just do not have access to my dupe lib now.

Comment: Also, `%d` is not the correct format specifier for printing a pointer value. Use `%p` instead, but technically, that needs a `void *`, so you need to cast the pointer to `void *` in the `g_print` like this (I'm assuming `g_print` follows the same rules as `printf`): `g_print("%p\n", (void *)file);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this: if you want to change the value pointed by file, you must pass a pointer on the pointer...

```
static void check_file(GFile **file)
{
        g_print("%p\n", *file);
        *file = (GFile *) 0xdeadbeef;
        g_print("%p\n", *file);
}
```

And use it this way :

```
check_file(&my_struct.file);
```